# what is the meaning of "var placeId = json['candidates'][0]['place_id'] as String;" in flutter google maps?

Tags: json, flutter, json-deserialization, google-maps-flutter

I m sorry for asking like those simple questions. because I m noob to json and flutter.
I just need to understand this code segment. Please help.

```
var placeId = json['candidates'][0]['place_id'] as String;
```

I just found this code part when I need  to get placeId for a place in google map using API_KEY in flutter project. This is the full code part of it.

```
  Future<String> getPlaceId(String input) async {
final String url =
    'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=$input&inputtype=textquery&key=$key';
var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
    'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=$input&inputtype=textquery&key=$key'));
var json = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);

var placeId = json['candidates'][0]['place_id'] as String;
print(placeId);
return placeId;}
```

I found this code part from this video https://youtu.be/tfFByL7F-00

I need to know what is ['candidates'][0] and what is ['place_id'] how can I found those properties for place id. Are there more properties for placeId.
where can I learn this type of code **json['candidates'][0]['place_id']**.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

That code mean, it will access array `candidates` index number 0, and get `place_id` of candidates index number 0 {which is fisrt object in that array}, and then return the value as a String. So its something like this :

```
{
   "status": 200,
   "candidates": [
      {
         "place_id": 1
      },
      {
         "place_id": 2
      }
   ]
}
```

It will return 1 as its value